# Remove Google Analytics log in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, google-analytics

How can I remove google analytics log code in Xcode?

The code looks like:

```
2016-08-19 18:07:52.614 Rechner+[1409:490065] VERBOSE: GoogleAnalytics 3.16 -[GAIBatchingDispatcher persist:] (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:518): Saved hit: {
    parameters =     {
        "&_crc" = 0;
        "&_s" = 167;
        "&_u" = ".oK9L";
```

I added it over `pod init` to my project

Answer (score 0):

You can disable debug mode by setting

`[GAI sharedInstance].debug = NO;`

Or depending on your GA version:

`[[[GAI sharedInstance] logger] setLogLevel:kGAILogLevelError];`